# usage of except and store error in a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I need to catch all the errors,exceptions, and everything that stops the execution of a code and store it in a variable.
I want something like this:

```
try:
    Error generating code
except as err:
    print err
```

But this doesnt work. Is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`except as err:` doesn't work because the correct syntax is:

```
except TypeOfError as somename:
```

To catch any type of error, use `Exception` as the type,
it is the common base class for all non-exit exceptions in Python:

```
try:
    # Error generating code
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

`err` will be an instance of the actual exception that was raised,
you can see its correct type with `type(err)`,
and it's attributes and methods with `dir(err)`.

Keep in mind that it's recommended to use the most specific type of exception that may be raised.

See more details in Python's [tutorial on error handling](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html).